# iOS NSPredicate that checks against NSManagedObject properties and return values of instance methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a model object `Place` that have a couple of standards properties. It also have some custom instance method defined in a `Mogenerated` subclass. That looks something like this:

```
- (NSString *) currentName {
    return [self valueFromArrayData:self.nameLocaleMap atIndex:...];
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to make a `NSpredicate` would function something like this somehow:

```
// I have tried this predicate, and it doesn't work... IS it possible to do something similar to get the wanted effect?
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```

Or alternatively, if it's possible to evaluate/compare the contents of a `NSData` property with a NSString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate should work, but only when run locally against, for example, an array (`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`).

Your predicate can not be used with Core Data because `currentName` doesn't exist at the data store level.